# TraMineR - dont print message of seqdef

Tags: sequence-analysis, traminer

Is there a possibility to disable the initial message (1) when creating a sequence with `seqdef` `library(TraMineR)` ?

(1) this message

```
 [>] coding void elements with '%' and missing values with '*'
 [>] 6 distinct states appear in the data: 
     1 = M
     2 = MC
 ...
```

For instance,

```
LCS.ex <- c("S-U-S-M-S-U", "U-S-SC-MC", "S-U-M-S-SC-UC-MC")
seqdef(LCS.ex)
```

Subsequently, is it possible to use TraMineR functions (such as `seqdist` or `seqLLCS`) without using a TraMineR object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can suppress the messages with `suppressMessages`

```
suppressMessages(seqdef(LCS.ex))
```

As for your second question: `seqdist` and `seqLLCS` work only for state sequence objects. So, you need to transform your data in such a object.

Comment: so embedded as `seq = suppressMessages(seqdef(LCS.ex))`. Thanks